# Unable to login to ubuntu after it goes to lock screen automatically

Tags: 20.04, lock-screen

I am not able to login in the auto lock screen after turning on automatic suspend. will turning off auto suspend resolve this

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the lock on suspend:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver ubuntu-lock-on-suspend 'false'
```

OR completely disable the whole lock screen:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen 'true'
```